# First order differential calculus over algebra $A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, graded-rings

Let $A$ be a unital algebra and $d_u$ is universal differential given by $d_u(x)=1 \otimes x-x \otimes 1$. It is viewed as the map $A \to \Omega_u^1(A)$ where $\Omega_u^1(A)=\ker m$ is the kernel of multiplication map $A \otimes A \to A$. One shows that $\Omega_u^1(A)$ is generated (as a left $A$ module) by $d_u(A)$ and since $d_u(1)=0$ the map $A / (\mathbb{C}1) \ni \overline{y} \mapsto d_u(y)$ is well defined. Consider the mapping $x \otimes \overline{y} \mapsto xd_u(y)$ acting as $A \otimes A /\mathbb{C}1 \to \Omega_u^1(A)$.

> **Question** Why this map is one-to-one?

Comment: Show that the mapping $\Omega^1_u \left(A\right) \to A \otimes \left(A / \mathbb C 1\right)$ which is defined as the restriction of the $\mathbb{C}$-linear mapping $\Phi : A \otimes A \to A \otimes \left(A / \mathbb C 1\right), \  x \otimes y \mapsto x \otimes \overline{y}$ to $\Omega^1_u \left(A\right)$ is an inverse to your mapping.

Comment: Thank you, it is somehow embarrassing that the author claimed that this map is onto and "it is also easy to see that it is one-to-one". As far as I remember in dealing with maps between tensor products which has to be isomorphism, one barely never checks injectivity and surjectivity separately but rather one explicit identify the inverse isomorphism. So I was confused about this remark.